# Eclipse Java Formatter - break after '(' instead of '.'

Tags: java, eclipse, formatting, code-formatting, eclipse-formatter

I have a custom Eclipse Java Code Formatter that should break every line after an amount of characters in the line. But I didn't found where I can set after what characters Eclipse should break the line. If I have the following code:

```
System.out.println("Here is a very long line containing very many characters, but it is only one String (so no +)");
```

Then Eclipse breaks the line like this:

```
System.out.
        println("Here is a very long line containing very many characters, but it is only one String (so no +)");
```

**Question:** How can I make Eclipse to break the code after the '(' instead of after the '.', like this:

```
System.out.println(
        "Here is a very long line containing very many characters, but it is only one String (so no +)");
```

Comment: "You can't" is a very probable answer here.